# Get data of a document in firestore by giving a field value belonged to that document using Python?

Tags: python, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-retrieval

I'm new to `python`. I'm using a `firebase firestore` database for this project. After entering the `Admission_No`, I want to retrieve all the data in the relevant document  such as `name`, `grade`, `phone`. I tried to write a program for it. But I failed. Please help me to complete my project. Thank you all.

The Code might be full of mistakes. Please don't mind it and fix them for me.

**Sample Data**
[image: Sample Data Structure]

### Here is my Code

**.py**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

data = {
    'Admission_No': input('enter ad_no : ')
}

query_ad = db.collection(u'Users').where(u"Admission_No", u"==", data["Admission_No"]).get()

get_data = db.collection(u'Users').where(u"Name", u"==", data["Name"]).get()

if query_ad:
    print('Exist')
    print(get_data)

else:
    print("Doesn't Exist")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I tried many ways. But finally, I realized we should provide the correct `Document ID` for retrieve all fields of data from `firestore`.

**[Getting Data from Firestore - Method given in `firestore` documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)**

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

doc = doc_ref.get()
if doc.exists:
    print(f'Document data: {doc.to_dict()}')
else:
    print(u'No such document!')
```

**In my case I tried with this Code and it was succeed.**

```
u_name = input('Enter User Name : ')
ad_no = input('Enter Admission Number : ')

doc_name = ad_no + " - " + u_name

doc_ref = self.db.collection(u'Users').document(doc_name)

doc = doc_ref.get()

if doc.exists:
    Full_Name = str(doc.to_dict()['Full_Name'])
    Admission_No = str(doc.to_dict()['Admission_No'])
    Grade = str(doc.to_dict()['Grade'])
    Phone_Number = str(doc.to_dict()['Phone_Number'])

    print(Full_Name, Admission_No, Grade, Phone_Number)

else:
    print('No such document!')
```

Thank you everyone who helped me with this issue. ([@RJC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16531380/rjc))

Answer (score 3):

Upon checking your code, you declared another query `Name`, but you didn't include it in your data dictionary (`data`). You can remove the query `get_data` and just use your `query_ad` to check/get the value of your `admission_no`:

**Untested Code:**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

data = {
    'Admission_No': input('enter ad_no : ')
}

query_ad = db.collection(u'users').where(u"Admission_No", u"==", data["Admission_No"]).stream()

for doc in query_ad:
    print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

Since you used the `where()` to query your documents, you can follow this guide to [get multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection). Additionaly, by default, Cloud Firestore retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID, but you can [order and limit the data returned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

For more references, you can check this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#python) to perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore

Comment: It retrieves nothing. The output comes as `enter ad_no : r

enter name : r

Process finished with exit code 0` 
It Doesn't work for me. How to resolve it? Is there any other way? or should I change the database. (The document id of my database if custom [like ad_no + name]). Please...

Comment: I edited the code because of a mistake of it. Please check it.

Comment: Can you also share your sample data structure?

Comment: Okay. I added a picture. Please check the post, Sir. Thank you

Comment: I've updated my posted answer, you can try it out and test it on your end.

Comment: It still does not work. No any other way? or Should I change my program or add more details. Do you have any suggestions, Sir?

Comment: I suggest that you check the documentation in my answer for further information on how you can query or get data from Firestore.